# React component is not removed when changing path

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have my application created in create-react-app.
when I go to the path / "users / create" the page remains the component of the path users ("users") on the screen and the component is not deleted
When reloading the path page ("users / create") it works for me perfectly

I send screenshots of the code

-Routes

```
function App() {
  return (
    <LoginState>
      <AlertState>
        <DashboardState>
          <DocumentState>
            <UsersState>
              <RelasesState>
                <Router>
                  <Switch>
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login}/>
                    <Route exact path="/reset-pwd" component={ResetPwd}/>
                    <div className="wrapper">
                      <Header />
                      <div className="main-panel">
                        <RoutePrivate exact path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
                        <RoutePrivate exact path="/documents" component={Documents}/>
                        <RoutePrivate exact path="/document/:id" component={Document}/>
                        <RoutePrivate exact path="/usuarios" component={Users}/>
                        <RoutePrivate exact path="/usuarios/:userId" component={Users}/>
                        <RoutePrivate exact path="/usuarios/create" component={NewUser}/>
                        <RoutePrivate exact path="/usuarios/show/:id" component={User}/>
                        <RoutePrivate exact path="/usuarios/edit/:id" component={EditUser}/>
                        <RoutePrivate exact path="/comunicados" component={Relases}/>
                        <RoutePrivate exact path="/comunicados/:id" component={Relases}/>
                        <RoutePrivate exact path="/comunicados/send-email/:id" component={Relase}/>
                        <RoutePrivate exact path="/docslab" component={DocsLab} />
                      </div>
                      <Sidebar />
                    </div>
                  </Switch>
                </Router>
              </RelasesState>
            </UsersState>
          </DocumentState>
        </DashboardState>
      </AlertState>
    </LoginState>
  );
}

export default App;
```

"/usuarios"
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s3Ux9.png)

When changing from the page itself with a link to "create/users" it returns the previous component and below the new one
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ph8Vn.png)

I have noticed that when I remove the dynamic path from "/usuarios/:userId" everything works fine for me, what do you think I have done wrong?
Thank you very much for your support.

Comment: Hi Drew Reese
already add the code of the routes.
I do not add code the components because I think it is not relevant and the problem has nothing to do with that
The problem seems to me that it is in the routes because it does not render well only when I reload the page it works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I'm gathering that in some circumstances your code is rendering both the "/usuarios/:userId" and "/usuarios/create" paths. The reason for this is because you are rendering all your routes into a wrapper in the `Switch`. This seems to have the effect like it being rendered not in a `Switch` component at all, meaning all matches are returned and rendered. In other words, the `Switch` didn't match "/login" or "/reset-pwd" so it is "matching" and rendering the `div`.

Use a second "inner" `Switch` component.

The second issue is that a `Switch` component will also match and render ***the first*** match, so order and path specificity matter! `"/usuarios/:userId"` is less specific than `"/usuarios/create"`, but will also match `"/usuarios/create"` literally. Order the routes to specify ***more*** specific paths before ***less*** specific paths. Note that when you specify the order and specificity correctly you don't necessarily need to specify the `exact` prop on every route since matching is working for you now, not against you.

To be fully correct, only `Route` and `Redirect` components are valid children of a `Switch`, so you will want to render the wrapper into a `Route` as well. When this is done it will be more clear to you why the "nested" routes weren't working previously.

[Switch](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Switch)

> Renders the first child `<Route>` or `<Redirect>` that matches the
> location.

```
<Router>
  <Switch>
    <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>
    <Route path="/reset-pwd" component={ResetPwd}/>
    <Route>
      <div className="wrapper">
        <Header />
        <div className="main-panel">
          <Switch>
            <RoutePrivate path="/document/:id" component={Document}/>
            <RoutePrivate path="/documents" component={Documents}/>
            <RoutePrivate path="/usuarios/show/:id" component={User}/>
            <RoutePrivate path="/usuarios/edit/:id" component={EditUser}/>
            <RoutePrivate path="/usuarios/create" component={NewUser}/>
            <RoutePrivate path="/usuarios/:userId" component={Users}/>
            <RoutePrivate path="/usuarios" component={Users}/>
            <RoutePrivate path="/comunicados/send-email/:id" component={Relase}/>
            <RoutePrivate path="/comunicados/:id" component={Relases}/>
            <RoutePrivate path="/comunicados" component={Relases}/>
            <RoutePrivate path="/docslab" component={DocsLab} />
            <RoutePrivate path="/" component={Dashboard}/>
          </Switch>
        </div>
        <Sidebar />
      </div>
    </Route>
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

Comment: In other words, a set of `<Route>`s must always be a child of `<Switch>`

Comment: @zpr Not exactly... a set of `Routes` can be rendered anywhere within a `Router` component. The `Router` ***inclusively*** matches routes while a `Switch` ***exclusively*** matches them.

Comment: @PaulNuñez Hi, very welcome. Sorry, it's not clear to me if you are saying your question/issue is addressed/resolved by my answer, or if you've more question. Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi Drew Reese, it works for me perfectly.
We highlight what you mentioned earlier. - <Route> and <Redirect> simpreson are valid children of <Switch>. - A set of <Route> must always be within a <Switch> - The order and specificity of the route are important, so always more specific routes before less specific routes.

Thank you!